How do I define the Dynamic parameter for 'priority' in power automate flow
I'm trying to get the data from Microsoft planner into a sharepoint site. I have entered a code as per the attached images but I'm unable to see any data for the 'Priority' been exported to the sharepoint site. Can someone please assist on which instruction/code I should enter so that priority data from the planner can be shown in Sharepoint.


